# File upload via Websockets to Play Framework 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.0, Javascript and WebSockets. 
As in the example I have an AKKA actor that has knowledge of all the websockets. The single WebSockets.In have a ListenerCallback object that handle incoming requests from the client side. 
On the Client side I have Javascript/jquery to send formular data serialized in JSON to the websocket. This works pretty well for simple inputs. But now I want to do the same with a file. So I must convert the file data somehow to JSON data (e.g. base64). Does anybody know how to do this properly? I want to "collect" the file within Javascript and then send it via JSON to the websocket. I know base64 is not very efficient, if somebody has an alternative, please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, however you have to use the `WebSocket` and [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) API, which are only supported on newer browsers. Javascript has now a `TypedArray` datatype, which can be used to transfer bytes. For example, given the following HTML:

```
​<form>
  <input type="file" id="picture" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You need to observe the `change` event on the *file* input field. On the Javascript side (jQuery):

```
$("#picture").change(function(){
    var reader = new FileReader;

    reader.onloadend = function (bytes) {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://host/path");
        ws.send(bytes);        
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
}​);​
```

WebSocket PDU are minimally framed (only two bytes header), and when you `send()`, the browser should take care of setting the proper opcode for binary transfer, and on the server you should be able to read the stream of raw bytes. I am looking at the Play API now to supply a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about file uploads via WebSockets, but via plain old HTTP it's possible using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and `XMLHttpRequest` objects. Take a look at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown).